# Using dat file to create table in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I used `bcp` to create `.dat` file with my table. How can I now create table in `SQL Server` database using this file?

Comment: you cann't. BCP only copies data from tables and inserts it in tables. You have to make a create script for your table as well. In SSMS you can right-click on your table to create the script.

Comment: ok so how I can then copy data to table from dat file ?

Comment: `bcp yourdb.schema.table in yourfile.dat` but you might need other options, see the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: to I cant do it via sql server management studio ?

Comment: SO is for specific programming question.  Have you even looked at the documentation?  What have you tried?

Comment: The SSMS import data wizard can optionally create a table for you.